# Using select statement in pyspark changes values in column

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm experiencing a very weird behavior in pyspark (databricks).
In my initial dataframe (*df_original*) I have multiple columns (id, text and some_others) and I add a new column '*detected_language*'. The new column is added using a join with another dataframe *df_detections* (with columns *id* and *detected_language*). The ids in the two dataframes correspond to each other).

df_detections is created like this:

```
ids = [125, ...]          # length x
detections = ['ko', ...]  # length x
detections_with_id = list(zip(ids, detections))
df_detections = spark.createDataFrame(detections_with_id, ["id", "detected_language"])

df = df_original.join(df_detections, on='id', how='left)
```

Here is the weird part. Whenever I display the dataframe using a select statement I get the correct *detected_language* value. However, using only display I get a totally different value (e.g. 'fr' or any other language code) for the same entry (see the statements and their corresponding results below).

How is that possible? Can anybody think of a reason why this is? And how would I solve something like this?

**Displaying correct value with select:**

```
display(df.select(['id', 'text', 'detected_language']))
```

| id | text | detected_language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | 내 한국어 텍스트 | ko |
| ... | ... | ... |

**Displaying wrong value without select:**

```
display(df)
```

| id | text | other_columns... | detected_language |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | 내 한국어 텍스트 | ... | fr |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I appreciate any hints or ideas! Thank you!

Comment: could you show the full input and output ?

Comment: Does this mean when you execute `display(df)` command then column `detected_language` doesn't have the value `ko` instead it is showing `fr` corresponding to column `id = 125` ?

Comment: what happens if you use ```df.show()``` instead of ```display(df)```?

Comment: @LuizViola same behavior unfortuantely:
df.show() -> wrong values
df.select(['id', 'text', 'detected_language']).show() -> correct values

Comment: @Dipsy yes. It looks like the select part is somehow changing the values; or rather leaving it out changes the values.

Comment: if you filter df by id = 125, do you get only one row?

Comment: @LuizViola yes the ids are unique (created with monotonically_increasing_id())

Comment: Can you share the snippet of the output when you filter on `id = 125`?

Comment: when you run ```display(df.filter(df.id == 125))``` do you get ```FR```or ```KO```?

Comment: Also, try to clear the state of you databricks cluster and run again

Comment: @LuizViola with `display(df.filter(df.id == 125))` I get `fr`

Comment: @Dipsy The example in the original post is actually already a filter on id=125. I just added the ... to indicate that this is not the only instance where this behavior is present

Comment: Can try running df.unpersist() then check the values again? Or try restarting the cluster and re-execute the filter command again!

Comment: `df.unpersist()` did not help. I also tried clearing cluster's state, restarting and using different cluster; with no success

Comment: writing `df.select(['id', 'detected_language'])` and `df.drop('detected_language)` to delta files and reloading and joining them results in the correct values. This is a very ugly workaround, though. And the original problem still is very confusing